# Matching 2 tables with multiple duplicate values on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables as follows -

Table 1 -

```
Catalog Number| Section|    Qty|     Status
---
123|                A|          3|        New
---
123|                B|          2|        New
---
123|            C|          1|        New
---
456|                A|          3|        Old|
--- 
456|                B|          1|        Old|
-- 
456|             C|          2|         Old|
--
```

Table 2:

```
Catalog Number| Section|    Qty|     Status
---
123|                A|          3|        New
---
123|            B|          2|        New
---
123|                C|          1|        New
---
123|            D|          3|        New
---
456|            A|          3|        Old
---
456|             B|           1|         Old
---
```

I want a result that is something like this -

```
Catalog Number| Section| Qty|   Status|   Catalog Number| Section| Qty| Status|
---
123|          A|            3|        New|      123|            A|      3|  New
---
123|          B|        2|        New|      123|            B|      2|   New
---
123|          C|            1|     New|     123|            C|       1|   New
---
Null|            Null|        Null|      Null|    123|        D|      3|   New
---
456|                A|          3|        Old|      456|      A|       3|  Old
---
456|             B|           1|         Old|      456|       B|       1|   Old
---
456|             C|           2|         Old|     Null|     Null|   Null| Null
---
```

I have tried using SQL Joins and have not gotten anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!!

Edit -

This is the query I used:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Table1 a
INNER JOIN Table2 b ON a.CatalogNumber = b.CatalogNumber
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the two tables?

Comment: Can you post the SQL which is not working so that we can advise.

Comment: @KalharaAmarasinghe The 'Catalog Number' is the column I use to join the 2 tables if that is what you are asking

Comment: @MrSlim I have added the SQL Query I used to the question. I did an inner join on the 2 tables using the 'Catalog Number' column

Comment: @bbrumm The 2 tables are the same, but they have different data. There is one additional line with Catalog Number '123' on table 2 and one less line with catalog number '456'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN?

```
SELECT a.CatlogNumber,
a.Section,
a.Qty,
a.Status,
b.CatlogNumber, 
b.Section,
b.Qty,
b.Status
FROM Table1 a
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 b ON a.CatalogNumber = b.CatalogNumber;
```

This would show records in each table and NULL values where the tables don't have an equivalent record in the other table.

Answer (score 1):

You can use full outer join for this. The query goes like,

```
SELECT Table1.CatlogNumber, 
Table1.Section,Table1.Qty,Table1.Status,Table2.CatlogNumber, 
Table2.Section,Table2.Qty,Table2.Status,
FROM Table1
FULL OUTER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.CatlogNumber=Table2.CatlogNumber
ORDER BY Table1.CatlogNumber;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to perform a UNION of 2 separate queries. Something like this perhaps

```
declare @table1 table(CatalogNumber int,Section varchar(100), Qty int, Status varchar(100) )
declare @table2 table(CatalogNumber int,Section varchar(100), Qty int, Status varchar(100) )
INSERT INTO @table1
SELECT 123, 'A', 3, 'New'
UNION SELECT 123, 'B', 2, 'New'
UNION SELECT 123, 'C', 1, 'New'
UNION SELECT 456, 'A', 3, 'Old'
UNION SELECT 456, 'B', 1, 'Old'
UNION SELECT 456, 'C', 2, 'Old'

INSERT INTO @table2
SELECT 123, 'A', 3, 'New'
UNION SELECT 123, 'B', 2, 'New'
UNION SELECT 123, 'C', 1, 'New'
UNION SELECT 456, 'D', 3, 'Old'
UNION SELECT 456, 'A', 3, 'Old'
UNION SELECT 456, 'B', 1, 'Old'


SELECT t1.*, t2.*FROM @table1 t1 LEFT JOIN @table2 t2 ON t1.CatalogNumber = t2.CatalogNumber and t1.Section=t2.Section and t1.Qty=t2.Qty and t1.Status=t2.Status
UNION
SELECT t1.*, t2.*FROM @table2 t2 LEFT JOIN @table1 t1 ON t1.CatalogNumber = t2.CatalogNumber and t1.Section=t2.Section and t1.Qty=t2.Qty and t1.Status=t2.Status
```